# error passing a value in a bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm getting an error when passing an integer through spring.

```
<bean id="propConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="portListenerService" class="com.service.portListenerService" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true" parent="abstractService">
    <property name="devicePort" value="${devicePort}"/>
</bean>
```

portListenerService.java:

```
@Required
public final void setDevicePort(Integer devicePort) {
    this.devicePort= devicePort;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Because I am getting an error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portListenerService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int] for property 'devicePort'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Original must not be null

Even when I hardcode the port instead of pulling it from `application.properties`, I get the same error. Is some other problem amiss?

Comment: The error message mentions "Original must not be null". Isn't it a missing puzzle in the mystery?

Comment: Does your properties file have a property named `devicePort`? By "hard code" I assume you mean `value="1234"`?

Comment: maybe this is a stupid comment, but I've noticed that your bean `portListenerService` has a `parent="abstractService"`: AFAIK the child bean class must be compatible with the parent, i.e. it must accept the parent's property values. Does your `abstractService` accept an `Integer` for `devicePort`?

Comment: setting devicePort as an int rather than Integer appears to have solved the issue. This is rather strange, however, since I pass in dozens of other values as Integer in the same manner elsewhere...
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Could the `devicePort` related code be violating javabean spec - like in this [discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=77878)?

Answer (score 0):

It may not have anything to do with type of field. Usually this happens when there is a problem with setters, make sure the setter exists with return type `void` and your fields must start with lower case letter and setter would obviously have camel case for property with 'set' as prefix.

for example; I had the same issue recently and find out that the one of the letter within the property had different case in setter.

```
<bean name="gateway" class="com.xxxx.yyyy.zzz.MyClass" init-method="init">
    ...     
    <property name="stateLogIntervalms" value="${mux.state.log.interval.ms}" />  
    ...   
</bean>
```

definition of property in my class for correct like following;

```
protected Long stateLogIntervalms;
```

However definition of setter for incorrect like this;

```
public void setStateLogIntervalMs(Long stateLogIntervalms) {
    this.stateLogIntervalms = stateLogIntervalms;
}
```

you can notice that the second last letter 'M' is in different case than what I had in xml property and java class.

Happy Coding:)